# Place caption of tikzfigure on top

Tags: captions, tikzposter

I'm using `tikzposter` and I have a table that is defined in `\tikzfigure` environment. Because this is a table, I need to put the caption on top of my figure. Currently, I'm using it like

```
\begin{tikzfigure}[My caption]
\begin{tabular}
% My table definition
\end{tabular}
\end{tikzfigure}
```

This puts a caption underneath my figure. What should I add/modify in this to position caption on top of my figure?

Note: I can't use `figure` environment in `tikzposter`.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a `\captionof{table}{..}` (from the `caption` package) inside a `center` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a2paper]{tikzposter}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\block{}{
\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{Table caption}
\begin{tabular}{c}
a \\
b
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
}
\end{document}
```

You could also make your own `tikztable` environment, based on the `tikzfigure` one, though personally I would go for the above method.

```
\documentclass[a2paper]{tikzposter}
\newcounter{tablecounter}
%% #1 Caption
\newenvironment{tikztable}[1][]{%
  \def \rememberparameter{#1}%
  \refstepcounter{tablecounter}%
  \vspace{10pt}
  \begin{center}
    \ifx\rememberparameter\@empty
    \else %nothing
    {\small Tab.~\thetablecounter: \rememberparameter \par\medskip} 
    \fi
  }{
  \end{center}
}
\begin{document}
\block{}{
\begin{tikztable}[Table caption]
\begin{tabular}{c}
a \\
b
\end{tabular}
\end{tikztable}

\begin{tikztable}
\begin{tabular}{c}
a \\
b
\end{tabular}
\end{tikztable}
}
\end{document}
```